# Finite sum k*x^k

Tags: analysis, summation

Prove that $$\sum_{k=0}^m k x^k = \frac{x(mx^{m+1}-(m+1)x^m +1)}{(x-1)^2}$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-inftyn1xn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\sum_{k=0}^mkx^k=x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=0}^mx^k$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT :

Can you calculate
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{m}x^k ?
$$