# Sum of n*constant^n from 1 to N

Tags: summation

What is the value of the sum for n=1 to n=N of n * constant ^ n?

I have considered Geometric but with the multiplication by n I cannot get this to work.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Please see the answers to a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3151564/how-is-the-partial-sum-of-a-geometric-sequence-calculated/3151587#3151587).

Comment: Note that $\frac{d}{dx}[x^n]=nx^{n-1}$...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

This is an Arithmetico-Geometric Series.

$$\begin{aligned}
S_n & = \sum_{n = 1}^N t_k = \sum_{n = 1}^N \left[a + (n - 1) d\right] br^{n - 1} \\
& = ab + [a + d] br + [a + 2 d] br^2 + \cdots + [a + (N - 1) d] br^{N - 1} \\
& = A_1G_1 + A_2G_2 + A_3G_3 + \cdots + A_NG_N,
\end{aligned}$$

Here $\begin{bmatrix}a & d \\ b & r\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1& k\end{bmatrix}$ where $k$ is a constant.

$$\begin{align}
S_n & = \frac{ab - (a+nd)\,br^n}{1 - r}+\frac{dbr\,(1 - r^n)}{(1-r)^2}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\sum_{n=1}^N{nx^n}=x\sum_{n=1}^N{nx^{n-1}}=x\sum_{n=1}^N{\frac{d}{dx}x^n}=x\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left[\sum_{n=1}^N{x^{n}}\right]$$

There is your geometric series.  Multiply your result of the series by $x$ and then differentiate with respect to $x$.